# Stream parameter conversion between C++ and C++/CLI

Tags: c++, stream, c++-cli

I have a function in C++ which takes a stream as input:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &o, XObj x);
```

which prints `x` contents to `o`.

I wrote a wrapper for the `XObj` class in C++/CLI, which has a function to write the contents of the object to the stream:

```
void XObj_wrapper::to_stream(System::IO::Stream ^s);
```

The wrapper function constructs an `std::stringstream`, calls the `operator<<` described above to fill the stringstream and finally dumps the contents of the stringstream to `s`. It works, but my concern is the speed of the function: it dumps the contents of the wrapped object to an intermediate data structure (the stringstream) and then outputs it to `s`.

My question is, can this be done efficiently, i.e., without an intermediate data structure?

Comment: You could make a `streambuf`-derived class that sends data directly to the .NET `Stream^` object, but increasing the number of I/O operations is unlikely to give better performance than buffering the complete description of the object and then transferring it with a single `IO::Stream::Write`

Comment: I see. My concern is that the description of the object can take several megabytes, which implies that the string stream will spend time allocating memory o store the big string. Do you think this fact is neglectable?

Comment: I don't think it's negligible, I think it's good.  Anywhere you can put that data other than memory is going to be a lot slower.  Direct pass-through might be just as good, in the case where `s` is a `MemoryStream`.  For other stream types, buffering the complete object first is sure to win.